# Как реализовать перемещение по поверхности 3д объекта на равные расстояния.(UNITY 3D)

Tags: c#, unity3d, перемещение

Я делаю пошаговую РПГ с видом сбоку.

Особенности:

- Объекты - 3д(метод тайлов скорее всего не подойдет)
- Карта процедурной генерации(просто задавать точки вручную не выйдет).
- Имеются не только горизонтальные направления движения, но и вертикальные(лестницы)

Собственно, вопрос, **как мне реализовать пошаговую систему перемещения на 3д объекте?**

Как это должно выглядеть:
[image: Как это примерно должно выглядеть]

Важнее всего мне понять, как задавать клетки, как сделать само движение, я уже знаю.

Comment: Так а в чём проблема? У тебя есть размер клетки и её координаты, просто умножаешь эти координаты на размер и получаешь координаты клетки в пространстве.

Comment: @Qwer, карта планируется как процедурная, имеющая "бесконечный" масштаб, и для нескольких пользователей сразу. Совет хороший, но насколько это будет оптимизировано?

Comment: Если карта бесконечная, то двигать надо не героя и камеру по карте, а наоборот двигать карту под героем и камерой, как в бесконечных слайдерах делают. Иначе артефакты отображения возникнут из-за потери точности float на очень больших значениях. Но, в твоём случае, пока рано думать об оптимизации. Лучше сделать хоть что-то хоть как-то, чем ничего.